# How to split a string into meaningful words

Tags: c#, string

I wanted to split a string into possible word string. What approach should I follow.

Given string : thisisapineapple

solution 1: this is a pineapple
solution 2: this is a pine apple

Please suggest and explain the possible alogriths to get above solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: I this is not related to C#. It is related to artificial intelligence / machine learning.

Comment: So what have you tried already? I'm sure you're not expecting SO to do your work for you, do you?

Comment: This problem is discussed at length here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/

Comment: @Geert, do you split string in your daily work ? I don't , it is just for knowledge purpose and not to get work done.

Comment: @Wyck , awesome share. I was looking for something like this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm is powerful and not terribly difficult to implement.

Use strings from `/usr/share/dict/words` or `/usr/dict/words` as the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You need a scanner-less, [GLR parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser). They can handle words run together like this and can return ambiguous results. My own NLP library (AboditNLP) does this. Wordnet is a good source for the words.